# How to put a column as row names in a Dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to compute distances in R, but in my data frame the first variable (column) is a ID, for example I have this:

```
rownames ID     Amount1
1        0015     15
2        9812     25
3        1672     89
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
rownames  Amount1
   0015     15
   9812     25
   1672     89
```

Comment: It's not very safe to put the ID in the rownames. I recommend keeping it as a column.

Comment: My problem is I have to do MDS with a disimmilarity matrix and if I kept original rownames I couldn't see the groups, or after I made multidimentional scalement how can I see IDs in the plots instead of original rownames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
> DF <- DF[, -1]
> colnames(DF)[1] <- 'rownames'
> DF
  rownames Amount1
1       15      15
2     9812      25
3     1672      89
```

Answer (score 12):

Just use :

```
rownames(df) <- df$ID
```

Note that row names have to be unique if df is a data frame.